# SQL*NET not properly installed

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle, I am starting to work on my first project. I have installed Oracle Client ora11 and pl/sql. I have set tns names files under network/admin(tns names file is ok, I copied it from a colleague). Whwn I start pl/sql I got :

> Initialization Error, SQL*NET not properly installed...

I already searched a lor for this issue. The solution is to set the home directory and oci.dll on preferences. I did it already and nothing changed. I verified on registry, the home directory is set to C:\app\myname\product\11.2.0\client_1. The oracle name is OraClient11g_home2. I tried to put these two values and did not work. I have the same directory also on c:\oracle\... and also tried to put this path, no results.
If anyone have any idea what else could be the problem, I will be thankfull.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit client?  PL/SQL Developer only works with 32-bit clients.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you are right.It is Ora11_x64. In this case, what are my options?Thanks

Comment: You can either switch to the 32-bit client or install both clients on the same machine.  If you install both you may want to use the 32-bit instant client, which is much smaller than the normal client.